# Dynamic theme change in specific date in android

Tags: android

I just created an application with single theme. Now i would like to change the theme of android on specific date. That is if user opened the application on that date the application theme should be another one.. I created 2 theme in style.xml and it works if i load

```
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setTheme(R.style.AppTheme1);
 setContentView(R.layout.activity_my_home);
}
```

But i need to define this in every activity also. Is there a way to implement the theme change application wide based on specific date.

Answer (score 4):

Make a parent `Activity` and call `setTheme()` with date checks in it's `onCreate()` function. Extend all other activities with the parent activity and don't forget to call `super.onCreate()` in the child activities that are extending the parent `Activity`. Like,

ParentActivity.java

```
public class ParentActivity extends Activity{
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Date date; //Current date
        if(date is 11.11.2016){
            setTheme(R.style.AppTheme1);
        }else setTheme(R.style.AppTheme2);
    }
}
```

**Child1Activity.java**

```
public void Child1Activity extends ParentActivity{
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        //Do anything
    }
}
```

Comment: Good answer, you could also set AppTheme2 as the default theme in the manifest, then there is no need for the else and most of the time a setTheme call won't be needed.

Comment: Nice!

As a gentle reminder, be sure to call through to `super` as the first line of any override of `onCreate()`. This is essential when setting themes dynamically, because this needs to happen before `setContentView(int)` is called.

Answer (score 0):

if you  have to change the theme dynamically(depends on date) , you have to add to every activity.'https://github.com/akash09766/ApplicationThemeDemo'

Comment: This is untrue, Activity.java can be extended and the theme can be applied in this new class. See Bilal Haider's answer.

Comment: Nice implementation by Bilal Haider